# How can I create a method in VB.NET for a button's function?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a Viewer Form in VB.NET. I have a select picture button which I want to write a function for it. When I double click on the button in the viewer form design it was suppose to create a method automatically in the viewer form code but I didn't. So I had to create the method myself but I have an error which I don't know how to fix it. I tried to change the "btn" to "Btn" but it still didn't work.

[image: This is the image to the form]

[image: This is the image to the code]
[image: This is the image to the "Select Picture" button properties]

Comment: It seems the button name isn't `btnSelectPicture`, kindly show me the properties window when the button is selected. The code that links the function to the actual button is the part `handles btnSelectPicture.Click` and it seems to have an error there, please share what that error is.

Comment: When I put the cursor on the error it say "Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types."

Comment: I've added image to the properties window

Comment: select control, go to evants window in properties, select event you need, press 'enter'

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not sufficiently researched https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.100)

Comment: `it was suppose to create a method automatically in the viewer form code but I didn't`  What did happen when you double-clicked the control in the designer?

Comment: When I double-clicked it just created the class

Comment: Thanks for the property window image. It seems to be in good standing. Possible to share the project file? I feel there is something wrong with the Visual Studio setup/configuration, with the project file I can confirm if it has to do with project or not

Comment: @Eagnir yeah sure.... I can share

Comment: Ok, awaiting the update to your question with the project file link. Thanks.